# Kony unable to dismiss notification

Tags: android, push-notification, temenos-quantum

I'm developing an application with Kony, and I need to send some notification to user device.

If the device is an iOS one, the notification is handled right (the notification can be dismissed).

But if the device is an Android one, I'm not able to dismiss the notification from the notification center by swiping it and this is really frustrating for the user experience.

This is the JSON I'm sending to GCM:

```
    {
        "notification": {
        },
        "data": {
            "notifyData": [
                <some app related datas>
            ],
            "title": <notification title>,
            "description": <notification body>
        },
        "registration_ids": [
<device registration id>
        ]
    }
```

I've tried setting on "notification" block either "ongoing" and "autoCancel" flag, but nothing change.

How can I let the notification be dismissable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through with the below doc link,
http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Default.htm#Custom_GCM.htm#Modifyin

You need to modify the `notify_push_msg_clear` value in `pushconfig.xml` file. Change the value to `false` to dismiss the notification.